# CKEDitor 5 CSS on frontend is not applied

Tags: css, ckeditor5

I have successfully implemented CKEDitor 5.  I integrated the Classic Editor via textarea box, this makes is easy when saving the output to a textfile.

One thing I noticed though, is the CSS is not applied on the output.  I do not see any .css file in the ClassicEditor zip file that I downloaded.  It appears the CSS is integrated into teh ckeditor.js.  How do I apply the CSS if it's integrated into the ckeditor.js file?  When I use the editor, the css does get applied properly.

I tried searching ckeditor's website but I couldn't find a definitive answer, except that there is no content.css that I can link to.

To add, I have a main CSS that I thought was overlapping at first, but even after disabling my main CSS, it is still not applying the css from ckeditor.

As a result, the images don't scale and justify left or right, as it is not getting styled.

Please advise.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. FOr those in the same boat, what I did was I just loaded the .js script, and assigned a top container/div into class "ck-content".

Hope this helps

Comment: may i ask which script you load?